# how to convert to win 7 from win xp using the migration tool

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I'm running Windows XP SP3 and I want to upgrade to Windows 7 SP1. Is there a tool that I can use to migrate where I will not lose any of my data? I do not want to format and do a fresh installation.

Comment: Are you working on one partition, or do you have separate ones for data and system? Simple solution is to have you data on a separate partition, so make it, copy your files, clean the first one and install Windows 7 on a clean drive

Comment: I believe you can find the answer on Microsoft's website: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7#T1=tab03 && you can view some similar steps over here: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7.html